# UTF-8 characters in jersey web service and android async task

Tags: android, utf-8, android-asynctask, jersey

I am working on web service which send some parameter by post request.
But on the server side i always get wrong string.

As an example if i send "testing éra l'university" at server side its

Output is = "testing ?ra l'university"
It added ? in special character of french word.

This is my async task code

```
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("diplome_nom", diplome_nom));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ecole_nom", current_post));
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);     
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity( parameter, "UTF-8" ));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

and Jersey server as

```
@POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/v1/formation")
    public Response UpdateUserFormation (
            @FormParam("diplome_nom") String diplome_nom, @FormParam("ecole_nom") String ecole_nom ...)
{
String decodedValue1 = URLDecoder.decode(ecole_nom, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("ecole_nom after decoding => " + decodedValue1);
}
```

Comment: `web service which send some parameter by post request` ?? You ment: `my android client sends some parameters by post request`

Comment: if you try:  ecole_nom = ecole_nom.replace("%C3%A9", "é");...it work?